# Connecting to a squid proxy that uses the openvpn profile set up on that machine

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, proxy

ive been battling with this the last few days, im trying to set up a squid http proxy that i can connect to, and all that traffic is from a vpn.

Host Machine Application request ----> Squid Proxy -------> VPN -------> Internet (Then response back from here via same route)

I am unsure how to do this however, as far as im aware my configuration is correct, but it must not be due to the service not being contactable.

Please help

```
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
#include /etc/squid/conf.d/*
#auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
#auth_param basic realm proxy
#acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.20
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
#ttp_access allow authenticated
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128
tcp_outgoing_address 10.7.7.4
# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

I've tried adding authentication but had issues with that.

When i do a

```
admin@truenas[~]$ curl -v -x http://192.168.0.35:3128 http://www.google.com/
*   Trying 192.168.0.35:3128...
* connect to 192.168.0.35 port 3128 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 192.168.0.35 port 3128: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.35 port 3128: No route to host
```

It seems to fail, i can ping both the vm and the host machine, both ways so they can definitely contact eachother. Its probably something silly im missing.